# Add the Numeric column values and inserting total in XSLT

Tags: html, xml, xslt-1.0

I am  writing an XSLT script which generates an HTML output as shown below:

```
Alice           0
Bob    Maths    74
       Science  84
Mary   Maths    80
       Science  90
       History  95
Mark   Maths    70
Tim             0
```

I want to add a total cell for each student and the table should like

```
Alice  Total    0
Bob    Maths    74
       Science  84
       Total    158
Mary   Maths    80
       Science  90
       History  95
       Total    265
Mark   Maths    70
       Total    70
Tim    Total    0



<currentRow>
  <columnValue>alice</columnValue>
  <columnValue><null/></columnValue>
  <columnValue>0</columnValue>
</currentRow>
<currentRow>
  <columnValue>bob</columnValue>
  <columnValue>maths</columnValue>
  <columnValue>74</columnValue>
</currentRow>
<currentRow>
  <columnValue>bob</columnValue>
  <columnValue>science</columnValue>
  <columnValue>84</columnValue>
</currentRow>
<currentRow>
  <columnValue>mary</columnValue>
  <columnValue>maths</columnValue>
  <columnValue>80</columnValue>
</currentRow>
<currentRow>
  <columnValue>mary</columnValue>
  <columnValue>science</columnValue>
  <columnValue>90</columnValue>
</currentRow>
<currentRow>
  <columnValue>mary</columnValue>
  <columnValue>history</columnValue>
  <columnValue>95</columnValue>
</currentRow>
<currentRow>
  <columnValue>mark</columnValue>
  <columnValue>maths</columnValue>
  <columnValue>70</columnValue>
</currentRow>
<currentRow>
  <columnValue>tim</columnValue>
  <columnValue><null/></columnValue>
  <columnValue>0</columnValue>
</currentRow>
```

This is my xml structure

The XSLT runs for-each for each row as shown:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//wrs:currentRow">
        <xsl:variable name="theCurrentStudent">
        <xsl:value-of select="wrs:columnValue[1]"/>
        </xsl:variable>    
        <xsl:element name="tr">
       <xsl:if test="not(preceding-sibling::wrs:currentRow/wrs:columnValue[1]=$theCurrentStudent)">
        <xsl:element name="td">
         <xsl:attribute name="rowspan">
          <xsl:value-of select="count(//wrs:currentRow[wrs:columnValue[1]=$theCurrentStudent])"/>
         </xsl:attribute>
         <xsl:value-of select="$theCurrentStudent"/>
        </xsl:element>
       </xsl:if>



       <xsl:element name="td">
        <xsl:value-of select="wrs:columnValue[2]"/>
       </xsl:element>       




      <xsl:element name="td">
       <xsl:value-of select="wrs:columnValue[3]"> 
      <xsl:element name="tr">

       <xsl:value-of select="sum(wrs:columnValue[3])"/>
     </xsl:element>    
       </xsl:value-of>     
      </xsl:element> 
</xsl:element>
     </xsl:for-each>
```

Other than that everything works in the script, any ideas how do I do that in the XSLT script?

Comment: Can you post your XSLT and sample XML input?

Answer (score 1):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:key name="kSameStudent" match="currentRow"
  use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::currentRow
                     [columnValue[1] = current()/columnValue[1]]
                        [last()]
                   )"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <html>
   <table border="1">
     <xsl:apply-templates select=
     "*[not(columnValue[1]
           =
            preceding-sibling::*[1]/columnValue[1]
           )]"/>
   </table>
  </html>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="currentRow">
   <xsl:variable name="vGroup" select=
    ". | key('kSameStudent', generate-id())"/>

   <xsl:apply-templates mode="inGroup" select="$vGroup" />
   <tr>
     <td>&#xA0;</td>
     <td>Total</td>
     <td><xsl:value-of select=
       "sum($vGroup/columnValue[3])"/>
     </td>
   </tr>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="currentRow" mode="inGroup">
  <xsl:variable name="vPos" select="position()"/>
  <tr>
   <td>
    <xsl:value-of select=
    "concat('&#xA0;', columnValue[1][$vPos = 1])"/>
   </td>
   <td>
    <xsl:value-of select=
    "concat('&#xA0;', columnValue[2][not(null)])"/>
   </td>
   <td>
    <xsl:value-of select=
    "concat('&#xA0;', columnValue[3])"/>
   </td>
  </tr>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document** (made well-formed):

```
<t>
    <currentRow>
        <columnValue>alice</columnValue>
        <columnValue>
            <null/>
        </columnValue>
        <columnValue>0</columnValue>
    </currentRow>
    <currentRow>
        <columnValue>bob</columnValue>
        <columnValue>maths</columnValue>
        <columnValue>74</columnValue>
    </currentRow>
    <currentRow>
        <columnValue>bob</columnValue>
        <columnValue>science</columnValue>
        <columnValue>84</columnValue>
    </currentRow>
    <currentRow>
        <columnValue>mary</columnValue>
        <columnValue>maths</columnValue>
        <columnValue>80</columnValue>
    </currentRow>
    <currentRow>
        <columnValue>mary</columnValue>
        <columnValue>science</columnValue>
        <columnValue>90</columnValue>
    </currentRow>
    <currentRow>
        <columnValue>mary</columnValue>
        <columnValue>history</columnValue>
        <columnValue>95</columnValue>
    </currentRow>
    <currentRow>
        <columnValue>mark</columnValue>
        <columnValue>maths</columnValue>
        <columnValue>70</columnValue>
    </currentRow>
    <currentRow>
        <columnValue>tim</columnValue>
        <columnValue>
            <null/>
        </columnValue>
        <columnValue>0</columnValue>
    </currentRow>
</t>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<html>
   <table border="1">
      <tr>
         <td>&nbsp;alice</td>
         <td>&nbsp;</td>
         <td>&nbsp;0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>&nbsp;</td>
         <td>Total</td>
         <td>0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>&nbsp;bob</td>
         <td>&nbsp;maths</td>
         <td>&nbsp;74</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>&nbsp;</td>
         <td>&nbsp;science</td>
         <td>&nbsp;84</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>&nbsp;</td>
         <td>Total</td>
         <td>158</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>&nbsp;mary</td>
         <td>&nbsp;maths</td>
         <td>&nbsp;80</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>&nbsp;</td>
         <td>&nbsp;science</td>
         <td>&nbsp;90</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>&nbsp;</td>
         <td>&nbsp;history</td>
         <td>&nbsp;95</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>&nbsp;</td>
         <td>Total</td>
         <td>265</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>&nbsp;mark</td>
         <td>&nbsp;maths</td>
         <td>&nbsp;70</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>&nbsp;</td>
         <td>Total</td>
         <td>70</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>&nbsp;tim</td>
         <td>&nbsp;</td>
         <td>&nbsp;0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>&nbsp;</td>
         <td>Total</td>
         <td>0</td>
      </tr>
   </table>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Dimitre for providing solution and working on this. However, I modified my solution and tried to get it working and finally it works I will try this though and will post whether its working or not. Thanks once again. Appreciate it!

Comment: @user640232: You are welcome. I hope that this answer will help improve your current solution and get awareness of an alternative and efficient approach.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your foreach you will have to re-calculate the total score

```
<xsl:for-each select="student/subject">
    <xsl:variable name="scoreBase" select="score" />
    <xsl:variable name="calculatedTotal"
        select="student/total/score" />
    <xsl:variable name="calculatedTotal" select="$scoreBase + $calculatedTotal" />
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: How do you know the OP is using an `xsl:for-each` or what the XML input might be structured like?

Comment: Ojota - this does not work, also i want to insert total in there, i have posted xml and xslt script you may want to refer. thanks

Answer (score 0):

can you try this at the end of the foreach

```
<xsl:variable name="temp" select="sum(preceding-sibling::wrs:columnValue[3])"/> 
<td><xsl:value-of select="$temp"/></td>
```

Comment: I added this just before the end of for-each (shown in my code), it gives me one extra row with value 0 in the first column after each row. I also tried have rowspan count+1, which gave me extra one row after each with value 0 in the second column